# Group the data by quarter and count the occurrence of each unique values in a column

Tags: r

I had a dataset like with four columns

| quarter | Year | Product | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | Aspirin | VA |
| 1 | 2022 | Dolo | MD |
| 1 | 2022 | Aspirin | VA |
| 1 | 2022 | Aspirin | MD |
| 2 | 2022 | Aspirin | VA |
| 2 | 2022 | Dolo | MD |
| 2 | 2022 | Dolo | VA |

I am trying to get output like

| quarter | Product | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aspirin | 3 |
| 1 | Dolo | 1 |

and also bar graph visualization with the product on the x-axis and count on the y-axis.

I've tried many ways by using count, summary also tried to insert the summary count into table to plot the graph.

```
df_raw <- dmv %>% group_by(quarter, product) %>% summarize(count=n())
table(df_raw)
```

tried this also

```
df1<- dmv[dmv$quarter == 1,] #creating a dataframe for quarter 1
str(df1$product) 
df1$product <- as.factor(df1$product_name)
str(df1)
df_product_10 <- names(summary(df1$product)[1:10])
df_product_10_x <- unname(summary(df1$product)[1:10])
rows_id <- seq(1,10)
df2 <- as.data.frame(rows_id, df_product_10, df_product_10_x)
hist(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
data<-data.frame(dmv %>% group_by(quarter, product) %>% summarize(count=n()))
data<- df[order(df$count,decreasing= TRUE),]
q<-data[df$quarter == 1,]
q1to10<-q[1:10,]
ggplot(q1to10, aes(x= product_name, y = count )) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
df_raw[, list(count = .N), by = list(quarter, product)]
```

Comment: I got this error Error in `[.grouped_df`(df_raw, , list(count = .N), by = list(quarter,  : 
  unused argument (by = list(quarter, product_name))

Comment: need to use data.table